# How to show page number using pdf-tools in emacs mode line?

Tags: mode-line, pdf-tools

As title said, is there a way to have page number shows up in the mode line of emacs? I am not using any fancy power-line, this is stock emacs mode line.

Comment: What's your config?  It does it by default on mine (emacs26.1, pdf-tools 0.90).

Comment: Do you customize your `mode-line-format`?

Comment: My emacs is 26.3 and pdf-tools is 20191007.1436 downloaded from melpa.  I have no customizations for mode-line-format.  Like I said, it's stock Emacs with evil mode installed, pdf-tools install, yasnippet and some custom key bindings.